# I need some examples for a specific regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I have a regular expression and I need some examples to match with it.
This is the regular expression : `(?i)NNETAB-(\\d{4}(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2]))\\.[a-z]\\d{7}`

I tried to do it with myself like `NNETAB-201712.L2910000` but it doesn't match with it. Can someone help me please ?

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/cZu3Sl/1

Comment: Remove `(?i)` and try the rest with https://onlinestringtools.com/generate-string-from-regex

Comment: This shouldn't be closed as duplicate. It's obviously off-topic.

Comment: From the double backslashes I guess this is taken out of string context. I created some examples that do and don't match [here](https://regex101.com/r/SF3kRq/1).